# Python blueprints does not scale to due not working with database connentions

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I have sadly come into an issue with flask, blueprints, and restful with using a global db connection with mysql.  How on earth does the blueprints resource get the global db conn?  So if I define a global conn to python.connector then how can I use a database with blueprints?  I dont see a way to pass my db conn to a blueprint.

Note, I do not and cannot use flask mysql ext etc.  It must be a pure conn from python connector since I use fabric.

Here is my main code:

```
# views.py 
from flask import Blueprint
from flask_restful import Api
from resources.register import register
from app import app 

db = "This is my global mysql conn"


api_bp = Blueprint('api', __name__)
api = Api(api_bp)
api.add_resource(register, '/api/driver/register')
app.register_blueprint(api_bp)
```

Here is my resource:

```
from flask_restful import Resource
from flask import  request, jsonify

class register(Resource):
def post(self):
    data = request.json
    partner_ref = data['ref']
    partner_driver_ref = data['\driver_ref']
    query = """INSERT INTO %s (partner_ref,partner_driver_ref) VALUES ('%s','%s')""" % (ref,driver_ref)
    db.execute_query(query,select=False,table=None,key=None)
    status = {'status':'OK'}
    return jsonify(status)
```

Comment: How about you put the DB object in a separate file, and import it from both main and your blueprint?

Comment: But I will have 100 resources i.e. files and I dont want a separate conn per resource

Comment: If you import it, you will get identical objects across every module you import it. Check using `id(db)` in all modules. You should get identical object ids everywhere.

Comment: What does fabric have to do with your Flask app?

Comment: @Thrustmaster you are correct :)

Comment: mysql fabric, not the python package.  I use fabric for mysql sharding and read slaves per shard and have to use a shard aware python connection.

Answer (score 0):

How about putting the database connection in the `g` object?

```
@api_bp.before_app_request
def connect_db():
    if not hasattr(g, 'db'):
        g.db = db

@api_bp.teardown_app_context
def close_db():
    if hasattr(g, 'db'):
        # close your db connection here.
```

And when you want to use it, just use `g.db.execute_query(...)`